# Performance and impact of frequent du in btrfs

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, disk-usage, btrfs, storage

I’m analyzing the impact of scheduling a cron to run `du` on several large folders (10-20TB of files in total, # files is less than 100.000) every hour.

From what I understand `du` uses `stats` which reads inodes infos which get cached in RAM. Is this correct? Or is it disk cache? Or both?

If the above is correct can I assume that running `du` frequently will:

- not affect negatively my system performance wise and
- not put unnecessary wear on the spindles? *this might be a moot point but just humor me*

I read of several tools which offer some kind of caching for `du` output but my objective is to catch differences so not sure they are relevant to the discussion.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand du uses stats which reads inodes infos which get cached in RAM. Is this correct? Or is it disk cache? Or both?

"cached in RAM": yes, to a degree. Not completely, as file system buffers also eat RAM, and 100000 inodes/extent lists also need RAM, so, "both". ("disk cache" makes little sense: the data structure is on-disk, so that's not a cache, that's the underlying data).

> If the above is correct can I assume that running du frequently will:
>
> - not affect negatively my system performance wise and

You can't assume that. Even if the whole file system was in RAM, this is still a data intense operation, and will use both CPU as well as RAM and drive interface badnwidth.

> not put unnecessary wear on the spindles? this might be a moot point but just humor me

I've never seen spindle wear, so, um, no? Also, while your hard drive is in use, it spins - so, not quite sure this question is well thought-through!

> I read of several tools which offer some kind of caching for du output but my objective is to catch differences so not sure they are relevant to the discussion.

If you're after changes, you're probably approaching this backwards. `du` is probably *not* the tool of choice, then!

1. you could actually use inotify to get notified about changes in file properties. That's less load than traversing the full file system just to get a few changes!
2. `du` on btrfs *will deceive you about the storage used*. Btrfs is smart – copied files don't need extra storage until you write to them, sparse file regions don't, either, and the notion of snapshots and subvolumes makes this all a bit conceptually hard. `du` just adds up all file sizes. Not the same as [disk-usage](/questions/tagged/disk-usage)!

I'd propose you ask a new question (new post, not in comments) in which you describe the problem you're trying to solve with `du`, in detail, and describe your current approach. Your question here seems to ask about a small aspect of a very specific approach and I'm not sure this approach solves your actual problem!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Re the points on btrfs, I have no snapshots or copied files, all uniques, du is a simple tool to know, given a set of folders, how big they are. I don't even care about the difference in blocks vs bytes, just a rough measure is ok, that's why I use du. My question was more based on the two aspects I outlined and honestly what I was worried about is mainly the second point, stressful operation for a disk to be constantly run every hour? I remain wondering..

Comment: "stressful" for a disk is meaningless, disks don't get stressed more by du usage than by file-writing usage. So, the answer, no, it doesn't stress your platter additionally in any meaningful way. I wrote that! Also, you asked about whether it puts load on your system: yes, it does. I answered that too!